# Options to replace multiple patterns in multiple files in Windows

Tags: string, perl, powershell, replace

Source folder with 150,000 files, size of around 4 GB in Win 2003 server. Need to replace few patterns in XML files recursively.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "source_folder" -Filter *.xml -Recurse
Write-Host $files.count "files present in source" 
foreach ($file in $files) {
      (Get-Content $file.PSPath) | 
          Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "string1", "replacement1" } | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "string2", "replacement2" } | Set-Content $file.PSPath  
       Write-Host $file.PSPath " modified" 
}
```

This code takes more than an hour to complete. What would be the best way to achieve this? What are the options to reduce the time taken? Is it better to use PERL to do this? Suggestions would be of great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use .NET Classes for that.
That alone would save you a lot of time. Also you really should use v3 version replace (the .replace method). It's faster.

so it would look like this:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
      $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file).Replace("val1","val2")
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($file, $content) 
       Write-Host $file.PSPath " modified" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a perl one-liner - something like:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/oldstring/newstring/g' `grep -ril --include *.xml oldstring *`
```

If you want to keep a backup of the original files:

```
perl -p -i'.bak' -e 's/oldstring/newstring/g' `grep -ril --include *.xml oldstring *`
```

Answer (score 1):

try to modify your code like this:

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" -Filter *.xml -Recurse -File
    foreach ($file in $files) 
    {

    (Get-Content $file.FullName) | Foreach-Object {
        $_ -replace 'something1', 'something1aa' `
           -replace 'something2', 'something2bb' `
           -replace 'something3', 'something3cc' `
           -replace 'something4', 'something4dd' `
           -replace 'something5', 'something5dsf' `
           -replace 'something6', 'something6dfsfds'
        } | Set-Content $file.FullName

        Write-Host $file.FullName " analysed" 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

While I don't have the same resources to test this, I suspect it will run faster if you avoid so many pipes, like this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "source_folder" -Filter *.xml -Recurse
Write-Host $files.count "files present in source" 
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $s = Get-Content $file.PSPath
    $s = $s -replace "string1", "replacement1") -replace "string2", "replacement2" 
    Set-Content $file.PSPath  -Value $s
    Write-Host $file.PSPath " modified" 
}
```

The pipeline mechanism has some overhead this should avoid.  I'm interested in hearing back how much difference it makes for your case.

One other point, it might be good to add an `-Encoding` value to your Set-Content command to control how the output files are encoded.